# Git rebase using VS Code Terminal

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, rebase

I am attempting to perform a rebase in order to reword a past commit.

Using the command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

gives me the commit I want to edit, which I choose by changing pick to reword. I then click Ctrl+Enter.

At the next step, I then get the following message:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Committer: user <user@session.com>
#
# HEAD detached from 1abc2de
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'feature/seg' on '1abc2de'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD^1 <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   src/file1
#       new file:   src/file2
#       new file:   src/file3
```

To which I add the following text below as a new (more detailed) commit message, that contains certain key words for our instance of jira:

```
feat: adding segmentation for case x
```

My issue here is that at this step, Ctrl+Enter no longer works to move on. There is text at the bottom of the terminal screen showing **--INSERT--**, and I suspect that as long as this particular step is active, Ctrl+Enter won't work. What commands can I use to submit the edited commit and move on?

Comment: I think you need to find help on how to use `vi` as a git editor.

Comment: learn the basics of editing in `vim`, terminate the edit with `Esc:xEnter`

Comment: Thank you, that's right - I am unfamiliar with vim. In this particular case I managed to exit using ESC and then :wq, but I will be reading up on the available vim commands.